# Create watcher using python

Tags: python, elasticsearch

Can I use es.watcher.put_watch to create watcher from a python job. Does such method exists if exists how to use it properly so that a new watcher get created

I need a new watcher to be created after calling put_watch method from the python job

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.